# Kotlin: Reading all the files from a folder in the SD card

Tags: android, file, kotlin

I am a beginner at android development. I am working on a project where I have to read all the audio files present in a folder named **Audio** inside the **sdcard** folder. I have been looking through other questions and have found that a lot of people have used **getExternalStorageDirectory()** to get the directory path and used listFiles to traverse all the files inside the folder/directory. But I have found out that getExternalStorageDirectory() is deperacated. I am guessing **getExternalFileDir()** is the alternative to that but I am unable to understand how to use this. I have been stuck at this question for hours any help at all will be really appreciated.

After seeing the suggestions I have made these changes to my code I also changed  the folder to Audiobook and put my files there

```
 fun getaudio(){
              val dir: File = File("/sdcard/Audiobooks/01 Furies of Calderon")

              if (dir.exists()) { 
                  var files = dir.listFiles()
                 Log.d("mytag","No of files is ${files.size}")


              }
```

But here files is returning empty with zero size I have given permission in my manifest file as well but it is still not working.
Below is a ss of my directory structure
[image]

Comment: Have you created the audio folder or you are yet to create the folder from wherein you wil read it ?

Comment: Just use full path to wanted audio folder. It can have only one full path so it does not make sense to talk about getExternalFilesDir as alternative. You have to come up with the right path.

Comment: `I have to read all the audio files present in a folder named Audio inside the sdcard folder. ` It is unclear what you mean with sdcard. A removable micro sd card? Why dont you tell us full path?

Comment: the full path is : /sdcard/Audio and yes I have already created the folder

Comment: Then what is the problem knowing full path? Just use File.listFiles(). It is the same path as /storage/emulated/0/Audio. So you could use getExternalStorageDirectory().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 val directory: File = File(
             Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
File.separator + fileName

            //File location
        )

        if (directory.exists()) {

            val files: Array<File> = directory.listFiles()!!

            for (i in files.indices) {
            //do whatever you want to
            }

        }
```

You should use the same File path which you used to insert . You don't need to use externalMediaDirs for this purpose .

For ease you can also use Apache Common IO library and perform the above operation in one line of code .

Advice : Use MediaStore Api for performing Audio Insertion and retreival operations(as suggested by the Android Officials ).

Comment: the files array is coming empty , also i have given permission to read external storage in my manifest file so its not a issue with that and the directory isn't empty as well i checked that too

Comment: I have updated the code , sometimes you need to use deprecated stuff since no alternate and legit way have been provided by the android Officials .